# how do you map java localdatetime to avro

Tags: java, datetime, avro

Im looking at understanding how we map localdatetime in java to avro.

is correct to use

```
   {
      "name": "example",
      "type": ["null", {"type": "int", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}],
      "default": null
    }
```

How do i set this on my avro object..

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
long epochMillis = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
```

should avro not be defined as a Long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per ealier comments i ended up using the below which gave me what i wanted

```
"type": ["null", {"type": "long", "logicalType": "local-timestamp-millis"}],
```

Answer (score 1):

`int` can't store epoch millis; you need `long`.

Compare these values:

```
        1,674,123,456,789 // current epoch millis (approx)
            2,147,483,647 // largest int value
9,223,372,036,854,775,807 // largest long value
```

Define the avro field as `long`.